# Can I Specify gas fees in the smart contract?

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, gas-limit, gas-price, truffle-contract

Deploying my contract on rinkeby cost ~12 USD in gas fees (using `truffle cli`). Is it possible for me to specify gas fees/set a limit in the smart contract so it costs me 0.5 USD, but takes longer to deploy ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Deploying my contract on rinkeby cost ~12 USD in gas fees

Your gas fees are a function of

- a) the gas required for deploying the contract, and
- b) the gas price you've chosen.

b) can be altered, but with a lower price usually equating to a slower transaction. If it's much lower than the rest of [the current market](https://ethgasstation.info/), then it's unlikely the transaction would be mined into a block.

a) cannot be altered unless you change the contract to make its code more compact or more efficient to execute.

> Is it possible for me to specify gas fees/set a limit in the smart contract

The contract doesn't know anything about fees. All you can do is set a low gas price when deploying and hope the transaction is picked up by a miner.